# Count User Return Rate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to find the user return rate.

I would like to know if a user came on the first day of of the month, if they came back during the rest of the month. I have lots of data spanning several years.

```
Table_01:
    -----------------------------------------------
        EVENT_DATE          | EVENT_ID |  USER_ID
    -----------------------------------------------
    2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 0021253  |   153
    2014-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 0021254  |   522
    2014-08-02 00:00:00.000 | 0021255  |   153
    2014-08-03 00:00:00.000 | 0021256  |   953
    2014-08-04 00:00:00.000 | 0021257  |   683
    2014-08-05 00:00:00.000 | 0021258  |   153
    2014-08-08 00:00:00.000 | 0021259  |   853
    2014-08-08 00:00:00.000 | 0021260  |   653
    2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 0022253  |   622
    2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 0022254  |   653
    2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 | 0022254  |   953
    2015-08-02 00:00:00.000 | 0022255  |   753
    2015-08-03 00:00:00.000 | 0022256  |   953
    2015-08-04 00:00:00.000 | 0022257  |   683
    2015-08-05 00:00:00.000 | 0022258  |   753
    2015-08-10 00:00:00.000 | 0022259  |   853
    2015-08-10 00:00:00.000 | 0022260  |   653

Answer: 08/2014 : 50%
        08/2015 : 66%
```

Microsoft SQL Server 2016. Compatibility level: SQL Server 2005 (90)

Comment: why 08/2015 is 66%?  Is not 3/9 ?

Comment: because only two users that came on the first day came back during the rest of the month.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```
SELECT tab.mnt
       , tab.year
       , SUM(CASE WHEN tab.cnt > 1 AND tab.frst >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)/SUM(CASE WHEN tab.frst >= 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
  FROM (SELECT MONTH(event_date) AS mnt
               , YEAR(event_date) AS year
               , user_id
               , SUM(CASE WHEN DAY(event_date) = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS frst
               , COUNT(*) AS cnt
          FROM table_01
         GROUP BY MONTH(event_date), YEAR(event_date), user_id) tab 
WHERE tab.frst >= 1
GROUP BY tab.mnt, tab.year
```

Comment: Sorry, but I keep getting this error: Column 'EVENT_DATE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: It runs now, but it isn't returning the correct answer.

Comment: ah ok, you want to know how many of the people who visited on the first returned, not the percentage of people who visited on the first and returned out of all the users of that month.
now it should tell you how many of the users that visited on the first returned in that month

Comment: "Divide by zero error encountered.", it seems to just return every row as zero

Comment: because users who didn't visit on the first returned 0, hope this is it.

Comment: cannot comment on the other answer, but I think the Group by that is missing is for the second select

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
  SELECT 
    dateadd(month,datediff(month, 0, EVENT_DATE),0) monthyear,
    max(EVENT_DATE) mx,
    USER_ID
  FROM <yourtable>
  GROUP BY datediff(month, 0, EVENT_DATE),USER_ID
  HAVING day(min(EVENT_DATE)) = 1
)
SELECT
  monthyear,
  sum(CASE WHEN day(mx) > 1 THEN 100. ELSE 0 END)/count(*) [pct came back later same month]
FROM CTE
GROUP BY monthyear
```